# How to display customer which have particular id?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display user which have particular id. For example for id 1 should display customer which have id 2. Now redirect me to customers/1 but show empty page. What can I do that display user ?
route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('customers.index');
});
Route::get('/customers', '\App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@index')->name('customers.index');
Route::get('/{id}', '\App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@show')->name('customers.show');
```

controller

```
public function show(Customer $customer)
{
    return view('show', compact('customer'));
}
```

view customers

```
a href=" {{ route('customers.show', ['id' => $customer->id]) }} ">
```

view customers/1

```
<tr>
<td>{{ $customer->first_name }}</td>
<td>{{ $customer->last_name }}</td>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ms-1">Updated</button>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Route:** you can customize the route as you like, but the standard is as follows:

```
Route::get('/customers/{customer}', '\App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@show')->name('customers.show');
```

**CustomerController:** when you do route model binding, it will do the findOrFail, so if you pass a customer that doesn't exist, you will get a 404 error automatically.

```
public function show(Customer $customer)
{
    return view('customers.show', compact('customer'));
}
```

**customers.show view:** basic view to show data compacted from the controller

```
<tr>
   <td>{{ $customer->first_name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $customer->last_name }}</td>
</tr>
```

Simple, yet elegant :)

---

You can read how laravel prefers to structure routes here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller

You can also go 1 step further, and let laravel do everything for you with the simple artisan command:

```
php artisan make:model Customer -mcr
```

Which will create, a resource, a migration, and a full resource controller.

Then in your web.php route:

```
Route::resource('customers', 'CustomerController');
```

Comment: I create function in Customer model which name `getuser()`, but now not show me particular user. This is my function  ` public function getUser()
    {
         Customer::findOrFail();
    }`

Comment: Spend some time reading my answer... try it out. Your getUser() function is also wrong.

Comment: I try it out, but not show me customer, I don't know where is problem

Comment: how are you going to the customers link? `localhost:8000/customers/123`

Comment: That's my link `onlineshop.test/customers/2`

Comment: ok, and do you have a customer in the database table `customers` with the ID of 2?

Comment: Yes, I have in database customer with the ID 2, when I am on `onlineshop.test/customers/2` show me view but not customer data

Comment: So far so good!, so how does you view look like, you can always do something like `<?php dd($customer); ?>` anywhere in your blade to see if the customer is being passed correctly.

Comment: I did that, but show error in IDE `undefined variable $customer` and in browser I not see data of customer

Comment: So great, then your problem is in the controller, did you copy my function `show(Customer $customer)` correctly? also in the top of the controller page, you should reference where the model is so on the top of the CustomerController 
`use App\Models\Customer;` put that under `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

Comment: Yes, I use `App\Models\Customer`, see my post, I added my current code

Comment: You are calling the wrong view, `return view('show', compact('customer'));` this will be inside `Laravel/resources/views/show.blade.php` -- but if you do `return view('customers.show', compact('customer'));` it will be inside of `Laravel/resources/views/customers/show.blade.php` the difference in folders

Comment: and again, your route should not use `{id}` it should be `Route::get('/customers/{customer}'`

Comment: I'm calling correct view, because view `show.blade.php` is in `Laravel/resources/views/show.blade.php` and if I go to `onlineshop.test/customers/2` show me html code but not display customer

Comment: Ok, the error was in route, big thank you for help me

Comment: yaaaay!! finally hehe, im glad it worked, if you liked my help please mark my answer with the check mark and upvote ^_^

Answer (score -1):

Try change you code in routes file to:

```
Route::prefix('/customers')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/customers', '\App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@index')->name('customers.index');
    Route::get('/{id}', '\App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@show')->name('customers.show');
});
```